# Decimal precision in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to add the decimal precision to be set for the values

Example:

```
select 1*1.00000;
```

output: `1.0`

Even tried with cast

```
select cast(cast(1*1.0000 as double) as decimal(5,2))
```

output: `1`

I want the results to be displayed as `1.000`. Is there any way to do so in hive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a table and test it. It works if we give the exact precision value as mentioned in the decimal function.

```
create table test1_decimal (b decimal (5,3));

INSERT INTO test1_Decimal values(1.000); //This will shrink it to 1 as the total digits is not five.

INSERT INTO test1_Decimal values(123.12345); //This results in NULL as it exceeds the total digits(5).

INSERT INTO test1_Decimal values(12.123); //This will give you exact result as the precision and number of digits fits. Ouputs as 12.123
```

So if the value matches the decimal function then it displays correctly else it shrinks or converts to NULL.

Comment: Oh Okay it works but i want the precision to be set by default whether my data is 1 or 1.000 or 1.0000 the final output should be as 1.000. Is there any other way? As my data is already in tables which are huge and i can't create a cte or temp tables.